# SOAP fault message

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have to send a SOAP fault message over HTTP to another web service if something goes wrong with a server, so I have this code:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <Response status="1">
        <Description>DESC</Description>
        <Errors>
          <Error>500</Error>
        </Errors>
      </Response>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is this a properly formatted SOAP fault message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a properly formatted SOAP fault message?

No it isn't. It should look something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>...</faultcode>
         <faultstring>...</faultstring>
         <detail>...</detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[The SOAP specification specifies what a fault is](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383507). Yours looks like an error result object of some sort which [has some disadvantages as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823100/soap-faults-or-results-object) for example.

Your WS framework should properly generate faults if you throw exceptions. If you are not using a framework but building the fault in some other way, then it must look like in my example above or it can't be called a SOAP fault.

Comment: ok, but i still have to have a response status and description and also fault code so is is ok to make soap envelope like this:  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <Response status="1">
        <Description>DESC</Description>
        <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>...</faultcode>
         <faultstring>...</faultstring>
         <detail>...</detail>
      </soap:Fault>
      </Response>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: @CrBruno: If you send a fault, the SOAP `Fault` must appear directly inside the `Body`. If you have some custom information that you have to return with the fault then you must add that information inside the `detail` element of the fault.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Bogdan I wrote this code and works like a charm!

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>500</faultcode>
    <faultstring>SERVER ERROR</faultstring>
    <detail>
      <Response_status>1</Response_status>
      <Description>DESCRIPTION</Description>
    </detail>
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But another question how to send a SOAP success message with a http code 200 an also I have to have some additional parameters in the message, this is a part of it

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
<Response_status>0</Response_status>
<Description>SUCCESS</Description>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So with this also I have to send code 200, how to write that can I write it like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>200</faultcode>
    <faultstring>OK</faultstring>
    <detail>
      <Response_status>0</Response_status>
      <Description>SUCCESS</Description>
    </detail>
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```